# black cells on embed youtube after resize page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube, embed

I have embed youtube or vimeo video on page html is dynamically loaded content using jquery, but on resize browser page create some black cells on side of embedded play or image(make same with images too!) also there aresome next previous arrows set on position absolute and on vertical middle of the page!
Can anyone help?

take a look at picture link:
http://www.4shared.com/download/1ExTgkplba/error_embedded.jpg?sbsr=9fffa10490e68179d42af0e10a8c85262cf3a55a544fc31&lgfp=3000

Comment: Could you please post the code ?

Comment: here is code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf27y0mu/

Comment: I realized that only happen only on ffox maybe is graph problem of browser!